# Vibrant Ink theme for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: editor, themes, intellij-idea

I've been trying unsuccessfully for about the last hour to find a ported version of the Vibrant Ink theme for IntelliJ IDEA. Can't find a working link to it anywhere!

Does anyone else use this theme for IDEA and if so do you know where to get a ported version of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I download and install "Dark Pastels theme for IntelliJ IDEA" from http://tedwise.com/2009/02/26/dark-pastels-theme-for-intellij-idea/ - works fine on both Idea 8 and 9! It looks little different to classic Vibrant Ink, but still nice!

Answer (score 3):

You can find two [textmate themes here](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/RUBYDEV/Third-party+add-ons). E.g. [vibrantInk.xml](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/download/attachments/4882442/vibrantInk.xml?version=1).

I modified vibrantInk.xml to use [Monaco font](http://www.webdevkungfu.com/textmate-envy-aka-monaco-font-for-windows/) (as suggested by Yi Wen; download the font and install it).
My [vibrantInk-monaco.xml](http://rapidshare.com/files/318964655/vibrantInk_monaco_mod.xml).

Also see themes at http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-1154.

Answer (score 3):

I just ported a version of [Vibrant Ink](https://github.com/eed3si9n/color-themes/tree/master/IntelliJ-IDEA/Vibrant-Ink) to IntelliJ IDEA with Scala support.

Comment: Nice project. But it doesn't support Java language, could somebody merge such support? Thank you.