# Can I set the environment of Intellij IDE like Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, intellij-idea

How can I make it look like Visual Studio?

I'm talking about Intellij Idea 9 and 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@cc You will find this Theme to your liking I think. Have a peep, I also use this in intelliJ (well I switch between this and default at times, I find at times reading JSPs a bit difficult). I find importing a theme if it suits you shorter than individually change colours but of course you can do this as well as @Timofei suggested ;)

http://tedwise.com/2009/02/26/dark-pastels-theme-for-intellij-idea/

You can install a colour theme by importing the particular setting and there is already a question in SO regarding this (applies to intelliJ 9 and 10, I use both).

[How do I install a color theme for IntelliJ IDEA 7.0.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187/how-do-i-install-a-color-theme-for-intellij-idea-7-0-x)

Another related SO question. 
[Vibrant Ink theme for IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817696/vibrant-ink-theme-for-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can (even more)!
`Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts`
You can save different color schemes to file (see screenshot).[image]

I'm not sure, IDEA has predefined color schemes, but you can google it.

Comment: But can I find existing settings?

Comment: @cc, sorry, could you explain, what do you mean?

Comment: files with the settings all set. I just load the file and I have those settings instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. you can find in the web themes that look like a ton of stuff.

Take a look at: https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes

Answer (score 0):

Use the following color scheme:

[Intellij-Visual-Studio-Dark-Theme](https://github.com/BenBanerjeeRichards/Intellij-Visual-Studio-Dark-Theme)

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/mkubdev/material-vscode-jetbrains : a .icls to add the custom color scheme, and a .xml to add to the Material UI Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Try this plugin -

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19177-vscode-theme

> disclaimer - I am the author of this plugin). Please feel free to log any bugs or improvements.