# Is there a way to import IntelliJ IDEA theme in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, visual-studio-2017

I really like IntelliJ IDEA theme, especially text appearance in code editor - fonts, way of highlighting things, spacing, etc.

I've recently started to use Visual Studio and I've been wondering whether there is a way of importing that theme from IntelliJ into Visual Studio 2017? Even if it's just text appearance rather than how the whole IDE looks, that would be really nice. I've tried looking up online and searching VS extensions but I only found [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879429/can-i-set-the-environment-of-intellij-ide-like-visual-studio) on how to do it the other way round (making IntelliJ look like VS)

Comment: would [this](https://draculatheme.com/visual-studio/) suffice ? also, what are the **names** of themes you are interested in? knowing names would help.

Comment: @AlexL I'm using default "IntelliJ" theme in IntelliJ IDEA so that's the one I'm after :)

Comment: I have a custom theme which i would like to use in visual studio. A Theme-Converter would be awesome :)

Answer (score 10):

I know this is way too late but it can help others.
In VSCode, press "ctrl + shift + x" ("cmd + shift + x" on mac).
Then:
If you want it for C++, search for "Intellij Theme C++" and install
IF you want it for Java, search for "Familiar Java Themes", install and then select "Intellij Dark Theme".

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio and **not** VSCode.

Comment: it helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a font called Voyager which is similar to Jetbrains IDEA theme
you can install the extension from Visual Studio

Go to Extensions
click Manage Extensions
type "Voyager" in the search panel and install it